# Вывести Hello в программе

Tags: c

Дан код:

```
void function()
{
    int i = 0;
    char r['D' - 'C' + ▲];

    for (i = '#' - '#'; i < ('B' - 'A' + ▲); i++)
    {

        r[i] = (char)(('+' - ')' * i));
    }

    if (r[▲] + r['-' - '+'] + +r['=' - '<'] + r['>' - '>'] == 12)
    {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Goodbye\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Необходимо вместо треугольника выбрать такое число, чтобы функция всегда выдавала Hello. Я перебрал все символы от 0 до 9 и взял от них ASCII код. Программа всё равно выдаёт Goodbye. Я просто невнимателен или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: А почему именно от 0 до 9 может вместо треугольника может быть что то в апострофах, т.е. любой символ. ну или вообще произвольное число

Comment: вообще вам надо цикл заполнения прогнать на некотором диапазоне чисел и найти `i` для которого `(char)(43-41*i) = 88` (если я конечно правильно посчитал число в IF)

Comment: @Mike, а я бы для начала забил на автоматику, и вручную привёл  бы все эти `'=' - '<'` к чему-то осмысленному :) Это недолго, но код понятней станет.

Comment: @PinkTux Ну так я и привел и получил то самое 88. Хотя конечно автору вопроса это стоило сделать самому до того как выкладывать код

Comment: @Mike, ага. Но, думаю, тут автор вопроса боится за девственность исходника. Я про то, что именно переписать *исходник*, и посмотреть на него уже после замен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну кто мешает просто провести *эксперимент*? :)

До 1000 это числа

```
157
413
669
925
```

Убедитесь [сами](https://ideone.com/n6H9ME)...

Comment: Как жаль, что у нас нету тэга <спойлер> )